# Magento 2 Get product options id for sql query

Tags: magento2, custom-options, json, configurable-product-options

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `sales_order_item` WHERE `product_options` LIKE '%2010%'
```

With the last bit being the decoded option id, I need to find two specific option ids to use inside this query.

My problem is that I can't load the options to be decoded.

```
json_decode($product->getOptions());
```

I've tried the above and got an error stating I'm using a object when it needs to be a string.

I need to be able to get the option ids from the decode json to filter the products ordered in the database with those option values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Inject sales order item class in your constructor**

```
 protected $itemFactory;
 public function __construct(
   ....
   \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemFactory $itemFactory,
   ....
 ) {
    ....
    $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
    ....
 }
```

**then in your function add the below code to get values from it**

```
 try {    
    $order = $this->itemFactory->create()
              ->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToFilter('product_options', array('like' => '%2010%'));
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```